# Confirm dialogue on submit for fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to figure out a way to add a Confirm dialog when submit is clicked but only if the fuResume box didn't have anything submitted.

Is there a way to do this with a Validator?

Comment: `OnClientClick` might help... You could run a javascript function to check and submit if requirements met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use btnObjectName.OnClientClick = "GetConfirmation();"  , return false if is "NO", return true if is "Confirmed"